# Collect() call used for a UDF function that returns pretty fat column (out of 2 columns in total) to avoid crossJoin

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

The problem is as follow:

```
'genre', 'top_tags' (250 rows)
----------------
Action, Array('bleeding', 'dying', 'guns', ...) - can hold up to 50k max. (avg is 4000)
Drama,  Array('crying', 'hard life', 'street')
```

And another table with movies, a genre and its associated tags

```
'movie', 'genre', 'tags'. (DataFrame size, around 23M Rows)
------------------------
M1        Action,  'guns', 'dying', 'bleeding', 'outside', 'worldwide'.  approx ~10 records for each movie
```

I want to iterate every movie and try to extend its genre similarity by comparing tags.
**NO Fuzzy algorithm**, just exact match.

I want to return a DataFrame  (the same movie, genre, tags dataframe) with new column called `potentially_related_genres` and a list of genres.

As I see it, I have two options:

1. `crossJoin` and compare two columns using UDF but this will be bad since it will lad me to iterate 5,750,000,000 rows. (crossJoin output)
2. pickle the results (do a `collect()` on the first dataframe (250 rows) and use right after within a UDF with all the logic, this by calling the original dataframe and use withColumn

`DF.withColumn('potentially_related_genres', my_udf('genre', 'tags'))`

The issue with the approach is that passing to the driver is a pretty big collect ( remember the fat column top_tags ).
and transfer this to all of the workers to be used. (the pickling and unpickling)

Any suggestion ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first option is not that bad if you cast it as tuple. What have you tried?

Comment: I was scared from the iteration at option 1 so I haven't tried it yet.
I did try the 2nd option, and it works if Im cutting down the fat column and limit the tags to around 1000. anything beyond that is not working due to the issue I mentioned above.

Comment: @Mabadai Maybe mapPartitions will perform much better wdyt?

Comment: If you go for a crossjoin, maybe cacheing and repartition the small df equally among all workers might help

Comment: @LuizViola, its to fat to cache. I wish it was easy.

Comment: Have you try to broadcast your smaller DF ?

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc, yea it's too big to broadcast due to the large column

Comment: Don't know your UDF's logic, but what about `explode`-ing the array in your `genre` dataframe, and doing a join on tags? Could be easier to distribute/scale horizontally.

Comment: Have you tried converting your big Array column into a string column, by joining all the string together ? You could still do string matching using Regex on tags

Comment: @YoanB.M.Sc I did tried that one, it helped me to use more tags one working with the data but couldn't take everything.

Comment: @mazaneicha I'll try this one, although It does not seem like the solution.
will keep you posted, thanks.

Comment: As i understand, you want only if both arrays are exactly the same, no sub-group of the other?

Comment: yea if movie has X tags I want to check how much tags I can find in an aggregation of all other genre tags (excluding the genre of the current movie) so something like set(movie_tags) & set(all_aggregated_tags_of_genre_X)

Comment: maybe pivot the genre df before the crossjoin to reduce the total record count? Does require messing with a lot of columns, i.e looping to apply your UDF 250 times

Comment: @ScootCork interesting thought - Going to check this

Comment: Ok, I tried @mazaneicha the solution didn't work :(
I'll now try to use ScootCork one, thanks!

Comment: Any further updates on this problem? Sounds like an interesting one.